# By using Generics How can I pass Map as a Collection to my method?

Tags: java, collections

My code as Follows:

```
public class CalledClass 
{
    public static <T> List<T> conditionMethod(**<T> map,Class<T> tableName) 
{
    //B.L
    return li;
}
}
public class PureCoding
{ 
   public static <T> void main(String[] args)
  {        
    Map<T,T> map = new HashMap<T,T>();
    CalledClass.conditionMethod(map,HomeWorkPojo.class);

  }
}
```

By this way I can't call method in CalledClass. How can I call the method. Here I want to pass Collection type Map and Class Name as Parameters to my conditionMethod().

In place of ** What type I will give.?

Comment: Map is not Collection.

Comment: yes you are right. Now I want to pass map as a Parameter to my method in main class and I want to invoke that method in another class How can I?

Comment: Using generics only...

Comment: It's impossible. A Map is a Map, and it's also an Object, but it's nothing else. So there is no other type than Map and Object that can be used to be able to pass a Map as argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So...if I understand you correctly, you wish to pass a `Map` and `Class` to your method.  In that case, the only generics you'd need are the bounds to the key and value of the map, and the type of `Class` you want (or wildcard):

```
public static <K, V> List<V> conditionMethod(Map<K, V> map, Class<?> tableName) {
    // implementation to go here
}
```

Remember what [generics actually provide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) - compile time safety with regards to types.  They're not some magic bullet; you use them as they are intended to be used.